# Second kivy screen ScreenManager accepts only Screen Widget error

Tags: python, kivy

I'm starting out with kivy and trying to write some simple little code to follow along with a video, but already I'm getting errors that he is not. I have the following code...

**my_tours.kv**

```
<MyTours>:
    Button:
        text:
            "Planned trips"
        on_release:
            app.change_screen("settings")
```

**settings.kv**

```
<Settings>:
    Button:
        text:
            "Settings"
```

**main.kv**

```
#:include kv/my_tours.kv
#:include kv/settings.kv

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        MyTours:
            name: "my_tours"
            id: my_tours
        Settings:
            name: "settings"
            id: settings
```

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class MyTours(Screen):
    pass


class Settings(Screen):
    pass


gui = Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return gui
    
    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        # Get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids["screen_manager"]
        screen_manager.current = screen_name


MainApp().run()
```

If I only include the MyTours screen in the main.kv file, everything works fine. For some reason, the Settings screen does not work, on its own or together with MyTours. Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but I cannot find a difference between the files or code of the two screens. The error is `kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.` What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Settings` is a well known class defined in `kivy.uix.settings`. That is the class that is being used in your `kv`. Try changing the name of your class to something other than `Settings`.

Comment: That's a good tip thanks! I also added @Screen to my kv files, which seems to have done the trick